# Linq search different table depending on switch

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to do some code which searches for the same thing but in different tables depending on a variable (table).  This is what I have so far

```
switch(table)
    {
         case "Company":
         var query = from c in db.Company
         select new 
               {
                   c.Id,
                   c.Name
               };
         break;

         case "Person":
         var query = from c in db.Person
         select new 
               {
                   c.Id,
                   c.Name
               };
          break;
          default:
          var query = from c in db.Service
         select new 
               {
                   c.Id,
                   c.Name
               };
          break;
    }
```

I don't like what I have as there is a lot of repeated code.  And this will only get worse when I start to add where clauses and orderbys etc.  Can someone see a nicer way to solve my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Provide one method for every type of entity/table. That makes your code more robust and reliable. Then you could even provide (optional) filters without breaking the code.

Comment: It's hard to provide a good answer when we don't know what you're going to want to do in terms of where clauses and orderings. Your problem isn't clearly defined.

Comment: This looks like a case for a generic repository.

Comment: You could use dot notation... `IQueryable table; ... case "Company": table = db.Company;break; case "Person": db.Person;break;...` and then `table.Select(item => new {item.Id, item.Name});`

Comment: Serv do you mean store the data in one table and have a field to identify the data type (company, person or service)?